# Counting user touches

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing an app, which is going to be used for a study I'm conducting. I specifically want to count the touches that the users make during the study.

I've already tried implementing something like that with `touchesBegan` extending `UIView`. That didn't work as expected though, since it seems to count each touch for every single view that's overlapping (so a tap on a `UILabel` within a `UITableViewCell` counts at least 2 times). I tried to fix that by using a boolean flag, which improved it but still didn't work as expected, as it missed a lot of touches.

Here is the code I used:

```swift
var softLock = false

extension UIView {

    override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if !self.softLock {
            self.actions += 1
            self.softLock = true
        }

        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        self.softLock = false
    }

}
```

To clarify: I want to count the exact number of touches that the user makes on the screen. For example, if a user taps the label in a table view cell and then taps a button within a cell, the app should register that as 2 taps.

I hope you guys can help me with this and thank you in advance!

Comment: Override `UIWindow ` class and use this method: `func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, 
        with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?` [Link to study](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest)

Comment: Thanks for answering! This is way better, as it now counts taps on keyboards, etc. but it still counts them multiple times (sometimes up to five times per touch). Do you have an idea how to fix that?